# A specific website stopped loading

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns

A certain website stopped loading suddenly on my laptop. All other websites work just fine. I have tried to:

1. Clear cache/cookies - not working
2. Bypassed router - not working
3. Change DNS server on router and/or network settings - not working
4. flush dns - not working

Please do note that the website works fine if I use a mobile hotspot connection, which is provided by a different ISP. Also, my friends who use the same ISP as mine are able to login without any hassles. I doubt it is a laptop-specific problem either as website doesn't load on a second laptop either.
I am in touch with my ISP to resolve this, but trying my luck here as they try to figure out this issue. Anyone else has faced this issue before?

Here is the output of tracert:

```
Tracing the route to remote.glbext.blackrock.com (69.52.135.23)
VRF info: (vrf in name/id, vrf out name/id)
  1 ge-0-0-0.bsr01.masceqx.nsw.m2core.net.au (203.134.2.77) 48 msec 48 msec 49 msec
  2 175.45.103.109 [AS 4826] 48 msec 48 msec 48 msec
  3 bundle-108.cor03.syd03.nsw.vocus.net.au (114.31.192.84) [AS 4826] [MPLS: Label 24344 Exp 0] 48 msec 48 msec 48 msec
  4 bundle-100.bdr01.syd11.nsw.vocus.net.au (114.31.192.81) [AS 4826] 48 msec 48 msec 48 msec
  5 Bundle-Ether12.ken-edge903.sydney.telstra.net (203.27.185.57) [AS 1221] 48 msec 48 msec 48 msec
  6 bundle-ether17.ken-core10.sydney.telstra.net (203.50.11.172) [AS 1221] 48 msec 51 msec 48 msec
  7 bundle-ether1.oxf-gw10.sydney.telstra.net (203.50.6.97) [AS 1221] 48 msec 48 msec 48 msec
  8 bundle-ether1.sydo-core04.sydney.reach.com (203.50.13.94) [AS 1221] 48 msec 48 msec 49 msec
  9 i-0-1-0-47.sydo-core03.bi.telstraglobal.net (202.84.222.61) [AS 4637] 48 msec 47 msec 3 msec
 10 unknown.telstraglobal.net (202.84.138.41) [AS 4637] 118 msec 118 msec 116 msec
 11 i-0-0-0-1.hkck01.bi.telstraglobal.net (202.84.173.22) [AS 4637] 116 msec
    i-0-4-0-1.hkck01.bi.telstraglobal.net (202.84.173.30) [AS 4637] 116 msec 117 msec
 12 61.8.41.102 [AS 10026] 116 msec 116 msec 116 msec
 13  *  *  * 
 14  *  *  * 
 15  *  *  * 
 16  *  *  * 
 17  *  *  * 
 18  *  *  * 
 19  *  *  * 
 20  *  *  * 
 21  *  *  * 
 22  *  *  * 
 23  *  *  * 
 24  *  *  * 
 25  *  *  * 
 26  *  *  * 
 27  *  *  * 
 28  *  *  * 
 29  *  *  * 
 30  *  *  *
```

Here is the mtr output:
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| |                                      WinMTR statistics                                   | |                       Host              -   %  | Sent | Recv | Best | Avrg | Wrst | Last | |------------------------------------------------|------|------|------|------|------|------| |                     www.routerlogin.com -    0 |  234 |  234 |    0 |    1 |   48 |    0 | |                                10.2.0.1 -    0 |  235 |  235 |    1 |    3 |   49 |    1 | |                            103.56.228.1 -   96 |   49 |    2 |    0 |   69 |  136 |  136 | | 14.141.116.229.static-Delhi.vsnl.net.in -    2 |  225 |  222 |    2 |    5 |  100 |    2 | |                             172.31.17.5 -    0 |  236 |  236 |   38 |   41 |   85 |   39 | | ix-ae-4-2.tcore1.CXR-Chennai.as6453.net -    0 |  235 |  235 |   47 |   51 |  100 |   55 | | if-ae-3-3.tcore2.CXR-Chennai.as6453.net -    0 |  236 |  236 |  116 |  118 |  166 |  116 | |if-ae-6-2.tcore2.SVW-Singapore.as6453.net -    1 |  232 |  231 |  114 |  117 |  166 |  122 | |if-ae-32-2.tcore2.HK2-Hong-Kong.as6453.net -    1 |  232 |  231 |  115 |  118 |  168 |  116 | |if-ae-2-2.thar1.HK2-Hong-Kong.as6453.net -    0 |  236 |  236 |  116 |  118 |  168 |  116 | |if-ae-7-2.tcore1.HK2-Hong-Kong.as6453.net -    0 |  236 |  236 |  115 |  117 |  167 |  115 | |i-0-1-1-0-1411-peer.hkth12.pr.telstraglobal.net -    0 |  234 |  234 |  108 |  110 |  159 |  110 | |i-0-3-0-2.hkth-core01.bi.telstraglobal.net -    1 |  232 |  231 |  109 |  113 |  157 |  112 | |   i-0-4-0-1.hkck01.bi.telstraglobal.net -    0 |  235 |  235 |  110 |  112 |  150 |  111 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |                   No response from host -  100 |   48 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | |________________________________________________|______|______|______|______|______|______|    WinMTR v0.92 GPL V2 by Appnor MSP - Fully Managed Hosting & Cloud Provider

I checked with my IT department and my IP is not blocked. What else could be causing this issue? Any thoughts?

Comment: not enough info - please provide the output of traceroute command and ideally a specific error you get from the browser

Comment: Could you include `mtr` output?

Comment: The website might have blacklisted the IP which is experiencing the problem.